# Pass array to variable parameter method

Tags: java

I'm using JCommander in a project.

Its documentation defines its [parse method](http://jcommander.org/apidocs/com/beust/jcommander/JCommander.html#parse(java.lang.String...)) to be like

```
parse

public void parse(String... args)
    Parse and validate the command line parameters.
```

so, it accepts a variable number of individual `String` arguments (to my understanding.)

However, my args are currently stored in an array of strings,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  CommandTemplate template = new CommandTemplate();
  JCommander jc = new JCommander(template);

  jc.parse(args); // <---  effectively what I'd like to accomplish.
}
```

Comment: Um, that code will work just fine.

Comment: `String... args` is affectivly a `String[] args` just with the nuance of you beeing able to provide the `array` as seperate parameters as of `("A","B")`, but using `(new String[] {"A", "B"})` will just work as fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code will already work fine. The `args` parameter of `parse` is already of type `String[]` - the `String...` syntax just means that the compiler is allowed to convert this:

```
parse("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

into

```
parse(new String[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" });
```

implicitly. If you pass a value which is already a string array, it doesn't need to do anything.

The JLS doesn't have a section specifically about this, but [section 8.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1) (method formal parameters) has quite a bit of information on *variable arity methods* including:

> Invocations of a variable arity method may contain more actual argument expressions than formal parameters. All the actual argument expressions that do not correspond to the formal parameters preceding the variable arity parameter will be evaluated and the results stored into an array that will be passed to the method invocation (§15.12.4.2).